# MVC Runtime View Controller model

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm creating few tables at runtime since we are receiving different data files frequently. e. g.: Health Insurance table

How do I create a MVC project for dynamic tables. I need to display health insurance data

in the view through the controller but without the edmx model I can't do this.

Any suggestions for this.

Comment: First, what language? Second, how do you expect to process this data if you don't even know what it looks like?  What do you intend to do with it?  Just show the data file you got?

Comment: Your request doesn't make sense.  You don't need the edmx model to do anything with a view.  Answer Becuzz's questions to start.